# How to correctly get mouse co ordinates in resizable canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, pong

I created a Pong game in JavaScript using the canvas element. Just to increase my knowledge, I also attached a function for resizing the canvas like so :

```
window.addEventListener("resize", OnResizeCalled, false); 

function OnResizeCalled() { 
    canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px'; 
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px'

    var gameWidth = window.innerWidth; 
    var gameHeight = window.innerHeight; 
    var scaleToFitX = gameWidth / width; 
    var scaleToFitY = gameHeight / height; 

    var currentScreenRatio = gameWidth / gameHeight; 
    var optimalRatio = Math.min(scaleToFitX, scaleToFitY); 

    if (currentScreenRatio >= 1.77 && currentScreenRatio <= 1.79) { 
        canvas.style.width = gameWidth + "px"; 
        canvas.style.height = gameHeight + "px"; 
    } 
    else { 
        canvas.style.width = width * optimalRatio + "px"; 
        canvas.style.height = height * optimalRatio + "px"; 
    } 
}
```

and then I centered the canvas like so :

```
canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
```

When I played game by resizing the browser, the game also resized correctly, but the paddle's movement was not accurate. It was not positioned correctly with the mouse.

I coded the mouse movement like so:

```
function playerBatMove(event) {
        mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        if (mouseY <= 19) {mouseY = 20};
        if (mouseY+playerBat.batHeight >= height-19) {mouseY = (height-20)-playerBat.batHeight};
        playerBat.y = mouseY; 
};
```

Besides this mouse problem, everything else is fine... even the graphics scale perfectly.

Is there any problem with the way I am getting mouse coordinates or my resize function has some bugs ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks. You can find the entire code here [Pong game on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWKJdj)

EDIT: I have declared the variables width and height at the beginning of the code.

```
var height = 500;
var width = 700;
```

Comment: Please clarify in the question where you define `width` in the line `var scaleToFitX = gameWidth / width;`  `height` has a similar issue.  Note all the alerts in the code pen make it difficult to view (computer always wins)

Comment: I have edited the question and also changed the code pen link. Now you can read it without interruption.

Answer (score 0):

I will edit the comment so that you understand easier

```
function playerBatMove(event) {
    mouseY = event.clientY* (newHeight/oldHeight) - canvas.offsetTop;
     //the scale factor is newHeight/oldHeight, or how much you multiplied
     // or you can just say 1/scaleY

    playerBat.y = mouseY; 
};
```

what you are saying here is that you want to take the mouse event. However take it only as if it was not scaled. the reason why `canvas.offsetTop` comes later is that the `offsetTop` is not scaled at all

ALSO REMEMBER : remove your css file, make sure this works then add your css file because you are transforming your stuff thre which am not so sure about.

Comment: Ok so I tried to do what you told. I multiplied the scaleToFitX to the mouseY in the mousemove event, but still there is no effect. I am doing it incorrectly ?

Comment: Did you remove the css transform?